# PySerial serial port send/receive

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I need some help on how to configure a new port and how to send/receive data from that port.

thus far I have:

```
import serial

ourPort1 = serial.Serial(
    port = 0, #how to define for rs-232, rs-485, or usb
    baudrate = 9600, #can i set this so its can also use 38600?
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)
```

I have tried reading the official documentation but I'm not sure how to approach sending 5byte commands and receiving 24 byte status packets with PySerial. Any help or references would help me a lot. I can't seem to find much for this module.

Answer (score 0):

This may be way too late an answer, but I'll take a crack at it anyway:

- the `port` property should be a string with the name of the port you want to connect to: on Windows it'll be something like "COM1", on Linux "/dev/ttyS0".
- You can then use `ourPort1.write(msg)` to send your 5-byte message, where `msg` is a string 5 characters long. Be aware that if you want to send literal integers as bytes instead of ASCII values, you'll need to do a bit of extra work.
- Use `reply = ourPort1.read(24)` to read 24 bytes into a variable called `reply`. Once again, this will be stored as a string full of ASCII characters by default -- you'll have to use `chr()` and `ord()` to convert back and forth between byte value and ASCII letters.

For more info, start here: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html